# Using soundmeter command line library to record sound on a seeed respeaker not recording

Tags: raspberry-pi3

For my work experience project I’ve had to make a sound detector with a seeed respeaker on a raspberry pi using the soundmeter module but it does not seem to be able to detect any sound as it just says that the min,max and average audio is 0 instead of something like 152,211 and 156 as given in examples.

All I type into command line is “soundmeter —-collect —-seconds 10” but it dimly shows the values as 0

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Doesn't sound like a programming question. Try asking at [raspberrypi.se].